# Move a floated box down one line

Tags: html, css, css-float, word-wrap

I am trying to produce an effect similar to a "sidebox" in text, where a note or heading at the start of the paragraph "floats" at the left or the right with some negative space around it, and slightly under the top like the date here:

[image]

A simple float like this does not allow me to move the note below the first line so I get one complete line of text:

```css
.note {
  float: right;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>
<span class="note">29 July, 1814.</span>
Exhausted with sickness and fatigue, I walked over the sands with my companions to the hotel. I heard for the first time the confused buzz of voices speaking a different language from that to which I had been accustomed;</p>
```

Merely setting padding or margins just makes the box bigger, but I want to move the whole thing down. Setting absolute positioning means it no longer reserves space and overlaps.

Is there any way to achieve this (and still have the note come first in the paragraph?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shape-outside` can do this:

```css
.note {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  padding-top:1.1em; /* padding equal (or slightly smaller) to one line */
  shape-outside:inset(1.2em 0 0 0); /* this will do the magic */
}

p {
  line-height:1.2em; /* height of a line */
}
```

```html
<p>
<span class="note">29 July, 1814.</span>
Exhausted with sickness and fatigue, I walked over the sands with my companions to the hotel. I heard for the first time the confused buzz of voices speaking a different language from that to which I had been accustomed; the first time the confused buzz of voices speaking a different language from that to which I had been accustomed; first time the confused buzz of voices speaking a different language from that to which I had been accustomed;</p>
```

with the margin:

```css
.note {
  float: right;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  padding-top:1.2em; 
  shape-outside:inset(1.2em 0 0 0); 
}

p {
  line-height:1.2em; 
}
```

```html
<p>
<span class="note">29 July, 1814.</span>
Exhausted with sickness and fatigue, I walked over the sands with my companions to the hotel. I heard for the first time the confused buzz of voices speaking a different language from that to which I had been accustomed; the first time the confused buzz of voices speaking a different language from that to which I had been accustomed; first time the confused buzz of voices speaking a different language from that to which I had been accustomed;</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Shape-outside, as described by Temani Afif is definitely the cleanest and most flexible solution, and I recommend it. But since you were told it was impossible, I'll show you an older solution. You can precede the floated span with another float of zero width and the height by which you want to move it down by, constructed by a `::before` pseudo element. In this case we'll use the height of one text line. Then the floated span just needs to be set to clear that constructed float.

```css
.note {
  float: right;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  clear: right;
}

p::before {
  float: right;
  content: '\200C';
}

body {
  width:375px;
}
```

```html
<p>
<span class="note">29 July, 1814.</span>
Exhausted with sickness and fatigue, I walked over the sands with my companions to the hotel. I heard for the first time the confused buzz of voices speaking a different language from that to which I had been accustomed; and saw a costume very unlike</p>
```

Comment: oh nice! we can also control the number of lines easily without any hardcoded line-height: https://jsfiddle.net/dyf9kvtw/

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this isn't possible, at least not in a way that would *in all situations*  move it down by one line (or whatever amount of lines or pixels).

The only thing you can do is to move the `span` element itself inside your HTML code, i.e. insert it at a later point inside the `p` tag:

```css
.note {
  float: right;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>
Exhausted with sickness and fatigue, I walked over the sands with my companions to the hotel. <span class="note">29 July, 1814.</span>I heard for the first time the confused buzz of voices speaking a different language from that to which I had been accustomed;</p>
```

Comment: Darn, that's what I was afraid of.